# Fetch API sometimes return 204

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I have this fetch request and my problem is, sometimes it returns 204 but sometimes it returns 200. I already tried to create a manual request using postman and it always returns 200. What could be the problem?

```
   export const requestJobRequests = (searchInput) => {

return (dispatch, getState) => {

    dispatch({ type: GET_JOBREQUESTS, payload: null });

    return fetch(`/api/JobRequest/GetJobRequests`, {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        body: JSON.stringify(searchInput),
        headers: getCookies()
    })
        .then(response => checkIfAuthorizeRequest(response))
        .then((data) => {


        });

   };
 };
```

Comment: Why do you think anything is wrong? A 204 means No Content. Many POST API's return a 204 because they don't return content. As far as why it changes, you'll have to look at the API itself.

Comment: i tried replicating the request through postman and it always return 200 thats why im confused

Comment: You are going to have to look at the API being called (/api/JobRequest/GetJobRequests). Nothing else can answer that question.

Comment: Why do you use JSON.stringify for your body? Do you do the same thing with Postman? On your server side, does your API expects a string or an object?

Comment: yeah i do the same thing i set my body as raw with the type of json

Comment: i fixed it already but i dont know what exactly the problem...  i have a 2 fetch request in componentWillMount and the problem is occuring but when i change the order from 2 request at the same time to chain request